# Question about groups: Find $|3|$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know this is probably a dumb question, but would the answer just be 3?  I'm pretty sure I missed the day we went over this in class and I can't seem to find anything in my textbook about this.
If the question were find $|15|$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$, would the answer be 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $|g|$ is often used to denote the order of the element $g$, which is the least positive integer $n$ such that $g^n = 1$ (written multiplicatively) or $ng = 0$ (written additively). If $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ be the group of integers modulo 15 under addition, then $|3| = 5$ and $|15| = |0| = 1$.